# How to link user post with its session using flask and MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am trying to link users post using Flask. `For instance, A user add a new product into the database from a form and it be displayed on its User template`.

I don't know whether the post should be added to the database linked by user Id or I just need to use its session.

I have a simple function that I use in the form to insert the post into the collection but I don know whether I need to improve to link with the session user?

app.py:

```
@app.route('/insert_product', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    products=mongo.db.products
    products.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

User template:

```
 <form class="text-center border border-light p-5" action="{{url_for('insert_product')}}" method='POST'>

            <p class="h4 mb-4">Add a new product</p>

            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                <!-- Category -->
                <select class="form-control " name="category_name">
                    <option disabled selected>Select Category</option>
                 {%  for cat in category %}
                 <option  value='{{cat.category_name}}'>{{cat.category_name}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- Product Name -->
            <input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Product Name" required>
            <!-- Price -->
            <input type="number" min="1" step="any" id="#" name="price" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Price" required>
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Add Image URL"> {% if session['email'] != None %}
            <input type="text" id="seller" name="seller" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Seller Name" value="{{session['name']}}" required> {% endif %}
            <div class="form-group green-border-focus">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="product_description" name='product_description' placeholder="Add product description" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <!-- Sign up button -->
            <button class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <hr>
            <!-- Terms of service -->
            <p>By clicking
                <em>Sign up</em> you agree to our
                <a href="" target="_blank">terms of service</a>
        </form>
```

I am able to display the post and all other CRUD functions. Just this small issue I would like to know to complete my project. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I just needed to match the seller name into the collection with the section name using pymongo declaring it as a variable `items=mongo.db.find({'seller':session.get('name')})`  looping to retrieve the products/posts:

```
@app.route('/user')
def user():

    items=mongo.db.products.find({'seller':session.get('name')})
    category=mongo.db.category.find()
    email = session.get('email')
    if not email:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('user.html', category=category, items=items)
```

Retrieving all the products done by its logged/session users:

```
{% for item in items%}
code here..
{% endfor %}
```